# HTML5 mobile app with dynamic content

Tags: mobile

I'm creating a mobile app using HTML5 combined with PhoneGap. On every tutorial I watched, they only use static HTML content.

How could I do to load dynamic content (from a MySQL database on a my server), like news for instance ?

Can't I use PHP? Or do I have to use ajax calls to get the data and build the HTML via JS/jQuery ?

In this case, is it better to save the data? If so, is there an alternative to localStorage ? Isn't it simplier to save datas in a javascript object ?

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 1):

I usualy use ajax to get data from MySQL, i think dats an alternative, however u can use webSQL for IOS and Android and IndexedDB for WP if u wish to use phone localstorage. But i think WebSQL is deprecated so IndexedDB will b the best alternative for localstorage check this tutorial for indexedDB by Pual Kinlan:

[TODO](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/)

Comment: You can add some info from TODO-tutorial here.